# Какая в данном случае должна быть связь между таблицами?

Tags: база-данных, mysql-workbench

Нужна помощь в определение связи между таблицами модель автомобиля и год выпуска. В данном случае сущность "Models" и "Years".[image: схема бд]

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, "многие-ко-многим"'. Разные модели могут быть одного года выпуска, в то же время одна и та же модель может иметь модификации разных лет.